# How to identify Microsoft Edge in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, windows-10, microsoft-edge

How can I identify **Windows 10** or **Microsoft Edge** users in **Google Analytics**?

Comment: Please add a constructive comment if you are going to down vote. Thx

Comment: We are working with Google on identifying Microsoft Edge correctly in GA.

Comment: Anybody got any updates for the new Chromium edge? How can we tell 'classic' edge apart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently Windows 10 / Edge users are appearing with a **user-agent** of:

`Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)`

My investigation so far points to `Windows+NT+10.0` being the key value in this situation, and these are showing as Operating System Version = NT.

The OS is not yet isolated in GA, but can hits can be viewed by using the following filters:

- **Audience** > **Technology** > **Browser & OS**
- Primary Dimension = **Operating System**
- Secondary Dimension = **Operating System Version**
- Select **NT**

Whilst we see historical activity for **NT** going back many months, we are seeing a definite spike in hits today (Win10 RTM date for those visiting this post from the future).

### UPDATE - 05/08

Windows 10 and Edge Browsers are now available as first class properties within `Operating System` and `Browsers` dimensions respectively

### UPDATE - 12/08

Both 'Windows 10' and 'Edge' dimensions are showing *far* fewer hits than `NT`. I'm not convinced this is logging correctly in GA yet.

Answer (score 3):

Edge is currently listed as a version of Chrome in GA. Each release has been listed with a unique Chrome version. You can use the site whatsmyagentstring.com to find the latest Edge UA string and get the Chrome browser version listed.

Search through the Chrome stats for that UA and you will find Edge.

Here is what happened when Edge was released with the User Agent "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10136"

This is Chrome 42.0.2311.135
http://1drv.ms/1JvKSCz

And here is what happened with an earlier Project Spartan UA that contained Chrome/39.0.2171.71

This is Chrome/39.0.2171.71
http://1drv.ms/1JvKsMg

Hopefully Google will add Edge soon and simplify matters, but until then, I hope this helps!

Comment: +1 for whatsmyagentstring.com, that's very useful in this situation. I have checked my RTM instance and agree that the UA provided is the same: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10240... so this begs the question - how can I report by UA in GA? The closest that I have found is Technology | Browsers & OS | Operating System | Windows | NT. I can see a spike, but this isn't just Edge users, it is all "NT" users :-(

Comment: Looks like Google just added Windows 10 and Edge! I found stats for both in my GA  account for August 4.

Comment: I've been reviewing GA over the last week or so and note that both 'Win10' and 'Edge' are showing _far_ fewer hits than 'NT'. I'm not sure this is logging correctly yet.

Comment: It looks like your assessment is correct. It was a huge spike just on the 4th and 5th -- and a corresponding drop on NT. All the traffic then shifted back to NT and Chrome variants. I should mention that the numbers for 10 are starting to spike again in my GA, so Google has made another change. It seems like they are at least working on it

Answer (score 1):

When I used [useragentstring.com](http://useragentstring.com/) while in a Windows 10 VM, the useragent strings were almost identical. [image: Edge on Win10 64 bit] [image: Chrome on Win10 64 bit]
As @MattS-LNO said in his answer, the version of Chrome that is used in the Edge useragent string is unique to Edge. In my screenshot, my version is 42.0.2311.135, which is the preview version. But that version doesn't actually exist as far as Chrome releases goes.  Also, the "Edge/12.10162" is added, but GA doesn't appear to recognize that yet.

Comment: I agree that GA is not correctly processing Edge results _yet_

Answer (score 1):

Here is an Advanced Segment available in Google Analytics Solution Gallery as a temporary workaround (look for Edge Browser there).
https://www.google.com/analytics/gallery/#posts/search/%3F_.term%3Dedge%20browser%26_.start%3D0%26_.viewId%3D7WxOe8NJRsa2kN-fryOrcQ/

Basically you are segmenting by Operating System version which would be either NT or Phone.

Helped me a lot.

Update:
A bit outdated but here is a good explanation
http://www.internetrix.com.au/blog/microsoft-edge-browser-is-not-detected-in-google-analytics/

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see there isn't currently and in fact theres unconfirmed reports that stats are recorded as Chrome by Google Analytics because it uses a similar User Agent

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10136

Comment: I saw that answer too, but there was no refernce / evidence about where the poster has found this information. From my own testing I have found that the UA isn't the same as chrome: Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)

Comment: Ok thats running from windows 10, I believe that Chrome type UA was running the Edge preview on Windows 8

Comment: Yep, we're trying to establish how many of our users have upgraded to Win10 RTM (released today). Our Java Applet won't work in Edge, and we need to figure out how much of a big deal this is ;-)